# Is there any way to get frame by frame using AVCaptureSession object in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I have to process frames which are captured by iPhone camera using my c++ functions. So I use `startRunning()` function to start the flow of data, but in what way I can process each frame?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is pretty straight forward. You need to

1. Create an AVCaptureVideoDataOutput object to produce video frames
2. Implement a delegate for the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput object to process video frames
3. In the delegate class, implement the method ([captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate/captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:)) that is called when a sample buffer is written.

For more information you can [read this part](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW3) of the AVFoundation Programming Guide. The code samples are in Objective-C not swift but i think you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

I created a class that may help you out: [CameraCaptureHelper](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/CoreImageHelpers/blob/master/CoreImageHelpers/coreImageHelpers/CameraCaptureHelper.swift) wraps up all the AVFoundation stuff and invokes a method on its delegate where it passes a `CIImage` with each frame.

Comment: I'll play with it! Thank you!