# How To Take Picture Automatically From Camera in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I am working on Project in which i am using CoreML for OCR. It works on Images Perfectly Now I Want To Process A Picture Taken From Camera Automatically. And I Have No Idea How To Do This.

Comment: what do you mean 'automatically'? you can grab frames from the camera and perform work on them as needed. you cannot do it in the background. Please explain what you mean and what you have tried already

Comment: Automatically means when a camera view presented it take picture without pressing capture image button.

Comment: how can i grab frames from camera???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255580/is-there-any-way-to-get-frame-by-frame-using-avcapturesession-object-in-swift

Comment: i have Read Your Article Before. Can You Please Explain It to Me that How Can I Use Buffer???

Comment: That is not my article. The information you need is linked in the answer linked above. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/06_MediaRepresentations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH2-SW4

Comment: There are lots of examples of how to do this on StackOverflow and on the Apple documentation. Please search for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class YourClass: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {


   }

   private func dismissPicker(picker : UIImagePickerController, img:UIImage){

   }

}
```

Comment: Hello Jean-François Fabre, Why you deleted my answer?. It''ll be helpful.