# how to autocapture an image from camera by using UIImagePickerController in swift

Tags: swift, camera

I am trying to capture a picture automatically from camera without clicking the camera capture-button and i am using the UIImagePickerController for camera usage.what should I have to add for autocapture?

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
{

var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       imagePicker.delegate = self
       self.openCamera() 

    }


func openCamera() {

        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera))  {

            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

            let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
  }


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){

 self.imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as?  UIImage

   else{
          print("Image not found!")
          return
       }
     }
```

Here I am clicking the capture button. But I want to take automatically a picture after autofocusing.

Comment: You cannot do it automatically using UIImagePickerController, as this is a UI component designed for user interaction. You need to use AVFoundation to capture the output from the camera. See this other answer for references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255580/is-there-any-way-to-get-frame-by-frame-using-avcapturesession-object-in-swift

Comment: can you share the code @RaviB

Comment: I think @Scriptable have already mentioned the solution of yours in comment..

Answer (score 0):

```
It is possible using UIImagePickerController as I R&D on this functionality.

If you want to autocapture an image from camera then you can use this below mentioned code. 
    
    1. First you need to Add AVFoundation framework in your project. 
    Select project -> Add AVFoundation framework in Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content Section

    
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
        
        let objCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        var objPreviewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
        var objCaptureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
        var objImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        var objTimer: Timer?
        var flagRepeatRecording: Bool = false
        var objOutputVolumeObserve: NSKeyValueObservation?
        let objAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            if !flagRepeatRecording {
                if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
                    objImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
                    objImagePicker.delegate = self
                    objImagePicker.sourceType = .camera
                    objImagePicker.allowsEditing = false
                    objImagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
                    
                    //imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String] // If you want to start auto recording video by camera
                } else {
                    debugPrint("Simulator has no camera")
                }
                
                self.present(self.objImagePicker, animated: true, completion: {
                    self.objImagePicker.takePicture() // If you want you auto start video capturing then replace this code with take picture() method startVideoCapture()
                    
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.cameraIsReady), name: .AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunning, object: nil)
                
                flagRepeatRecording = true
            }
        }

        @objc func cameraIsReady(notification: NSNotification) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.objImagePicker.takePicture()
            }
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    //        let tempImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as! NSURL?
    //        let pathString = tempImage?.relativePath
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
    //        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pathString!, self, nil, nil)
            
            self.objTimer?.invalidate()
            self.objTimer = nil
        }
    }
```